# append monthly datasets in SAS

Tags: sas, append

I have monthly datasets starting from 2012 till date. I want to write a macro that will append all monthly datasets with a select list of variables. The dataset names have the format: monthly_201201. Any ideas?

The datasets all do not have the same set of variables. Looking preferably for a macro that loops through each period, takes a select set of values from the dataset and appends to the master dataset.

This is what I was trying

```
%macro combine(prefix);

data combined (keep =   a b c d);
    set x.monthly_data_201801 (obs = 0);
run;

%do j=2012 %to 2018;    
    %do i=1 %to 12;
        %if %sysfunc(exist(x.&prefix&j&i)) %then %do;
            proc append 
                base = combined
                data = x.&prefix&j&i (keep =    a b c d) force;
            run;
        %end;
    %end;
%end;
%mend combine;
%combine(monthly_data_);
```

Comment: what have you tried?  this is not a code writing service.  Do some research, try some code, and when you get stumped, ask a question about your code.

Comment: Macro examples are here to help get you started: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/SAS-9-4-Macro-Language-Reference-Has-a-New-Appendix/ta-p/291716

Comment: apologies. Code added now.